# Partition function as a function of inverse temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

In statistical mechanics, I'm trying to gain intuition as to how to get an upper bound on an equilibrium expectation value of some observable $F$ in terms of the non-interacting expectation value.

Let's say the expectation value is given by $$ \langle F\rangle \equiv \frac{\int \exp(-\beta H)F}{\int\exp(-\beta H)} =: \frac{\langle F\exp(-\beta H)\rangle_0}{\langle \exp(-\beta H)\rangle_0}\,. $$

Here $\langle \cdot\rangle$ is the full expectation value and $\langle \cdot\rangle_0$ is the non-interacting expectation value.

Trying to obtain a reasonable upper bound on $\langle F\rangle$ I now use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as follows \begin{align}\langle F\rangle &= \langle F\left(\frac{\exp(-\beta H)}{\langle \exp(-\beta H)\rangle_0}\right)\rangle_0 \\ &\leq \sqrt{\langle F^2 \rangle_0}\sqrt{\langle \left(\frac{\exp(-\beta H)}{\langle \exp(-\beta H)\rangle_0}\right)^2\rangle_0} \\ &= \sqrt{\langle F^2 \rangle_0} \sqrt{\frac{Z_{2\beta}}{Z_{\beta}^2}}\end{align} where $$ Z_\beta \equiv \langle \exp(-\beta H)\rangle_0$$ is the partition function of the system at $\beta$.

*Question*: Is there any hope that $\frac{Z_{2\beta}}{Z_{\beta}^2}$ is finite in the thermodynamic limit (infinite system size) and if yes, what should one expect it scales like in terms of $\beta$? If the answer to this question is 'no' (which may very well be the case) is there another, relatively standard trick, to bound $\langle F\rangle$ from above in terms of the non-interacting expectation value in a way that makes sense in the thermodynamic limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any hope that $Z_{2\beta}/Z_\beta$ is finite in the thermodynamic limit?

No (except in pathological cases).

For a large, say cubic, box of volume $V$, the partition function behaves like
$$
Z_{\beta} = \exp\bigl[\psi(\beta) V + \mathsf{o}(V)\bigr],
$$
where
$$
\psi(\beta) = \lim_{V\to\infty} \frac{1}{V} \log Z_\beta
$$
is essentially the free energy density in the thermodynamic limit (up to a factor of $-\beta$, but it will be more convenient to work with this quantity). The existence of $\psi$ under very weak assumptions is a classical (and rather easy) result.

Observe that
$$
\frac{\rm d^2}{{\rm d}\beta^2} \frac{1}{V}\log Z_\beta = \frac{1}{V}\operatorname{Var_\beta}(H) \geq 0,
$$
where $\operatorname{Var_\beta}(H)$ is the variance of $H$ with respect to the interacting measure at inverse temperature $\beta$. Therefore, the functions $\beta\mapsto \frac{1}{V}\log Z_\beta$ are convex, and thus so is the function $\beta\mapsto\psi(\beta)$ (since the pointwise limit of a sequence of convex functions is convex).

In particular, except in pathological cases in which the function $\psi(\beta)$ is affine (or has an affine piece containing $0$), one will have $\psi(2\beta) > 2\psi(\beta)$ (since $Z_0=1$ and thus $\psi(0) = 0$).  It follows that
$$
\frac{Z_{2\beta}}{Z_\beta^2} = \exp\bigl[\bigl(\underbrace{\psi(2\beta)-2\psi(\beta)}_{>0}\bigr) V + \mathsf{o}(V) \bigr]
$$
will tend to $+\infty$ as $V\to\infty$. (Actually, the fact that $\psi(2\beta)\geq 2\psi(\beta)$ can be seen immediately from your inequality by taking $F\equiv 1$, but I thought it better to stress the role of convexity here).

> If the answer to this question is 'no' (which may very well be the
> case) is there another, relatively standard trick, to bound ⟨F⟩ from
> above in terms of the non-interacting expectation value in a way that
> makes sense in the thermodynamic limit?

Somewhat similar procedures can be used (sometimes) to compare the model with its mean-field version (which is also a product measure, albeit distinct from $\langle\cdot\rangle_0$). One example of this (for the Ising model) can be found in Section 3.10.2 of [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook) (see also Exercise 6.28 therein).

Comment: I should have mentioned that one can prove, under very weak assumptions, that $\psi$ is actually **strictly** convex in $\beta$ (actually in any parameter appearing linearly in the Hamiltonian). A proof can be found [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01877738). This is what I mean by *"except in pathological cases"* in my answer.